# Evaluate Flux of Field through Open Cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the flux $\iint_S \frac{<x,0,z>}{\sqrt{x^2 +z^2}}\cdot n dS$  where $S$ is the cylinder $x^2 +z^2 =a^2, |y|\le2$.

Solution attempt: I applied the divergence theorem but am not sure how to perform the integral over the cylinder.

Comment: You should separate the integral into two contributions : lateral surface and faces, ask yourself what is $n$ on these different parts. The result comes out easily once you notice what are the variables and the constants on each part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is the normal vector of the curved surface of the cylinder, and is orthogonal to the normal vector of the flat surface; thus the integral is simply the surface area of the curved surface.

Comment: Thank you. Now I feel quite stupid for missing that.